# Find a closed form for a parameter in an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, closed-form

Doing some math I came up to this expression, where $d,\epsilon>0$ 
\begin{equation}
\left(1+\frac{d}{2}+{\epsilon}d\right)^{20}
<\left(1+\frac{d}{2}-{\epsilon}d\right)^{21}
\end{equation} 
Since for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ it holds, for every fixed $d>0$ one can find an enough small $\epsilon$ such that this inequality holds.

I'm curious if there is a closed form expressing $\epsilon$ as a function of $d$ for which the inequality holds, in other words a function $\epsilon(d)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left(1+\frac{d}{2}+d\cdot{\epsilon(d)}\right)^{20}
<\left(1+\frac{d}{2}-d\cdot{\epsilon(d)}\right)^{21}
\end{equation} 
holds for every $d>0$.

I guess it could be something like
\begin{equation}
\epsilon(d)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{d^c+c}& \text{if }d\geqslant 1\\
d^c&\text{if }d< 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $c$ big enough, and with the aid of a mathematical software it could be determined explicitly, but I have no experience in using them.

Maybe, am I missing some straightforward manipulations?

Comment: Tried few calculations in Maple and seems it works for all $\epsilon \leq \frac{1}{82}$, independently on $d$. But I don't see why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one showed an interest in it since more than ten years.

Comment: @KurtG. I'm fine with closing it.

Comment: @Sil I think I have a proof for it, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ both sides are positive and thus, taking
the logarithm of both sides
\begin{align*}
\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right)^{20} & <\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\right)^{21}\\
\iff0 & <21\log\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\right)-20\log\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right).
\end{align*}
Let us call the r.h.s.
$$
f(d)=21\log\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\right)-20\log\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right)
$$
We have $f(0)=0$. Hence, if $f'(d)>0$ for all $d\geq 0$, the original inequality is always true.
We indeed have
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(d) & = & 21\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon}{1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)}-20\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}{1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)},
\end{eqnarray*}
which is strictly positive if
\begin{align*}
d\cdot\left(21\left(\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon^{2}\right)-20\left(\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon^{2}\right)\right) & >20\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)-21\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\\
\iff21\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right) & >20\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\left(1+d\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)\right)\\
\iff d\left(\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon^{2}\right) & > 41\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}\\
\iff d & >\frac{41\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}}{\left(\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon^{2}\right)}.
\end{align*}
The latter inequality is always true if $\epsilon < \frac{1}{82}$.